# CSS grid and flex box not working - cannot move items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want my colours to start at the top left within the color-select (green box), and for some reason the last item is off screen. How do I make it start at top left and all colours contained within the color-select (green box) section?

Also, when the site is in mobile view, how do I make each item (colours) smaller and in a row of six? (I have 12 colours but couldn't display them all here).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 90px 1fr 1fr 80px 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header"
    "main main main main main"
    "main main main main main"
    "carousel carousel carousel carousel carousel"
    "color-select color-select color-select color-select color-select"
    "about about about about about"
    "social social social social social"
    "footer footer footer footer footer";
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  main.main {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  /* background-color: red; */
  margin: 10px;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 5px;
  top: 15px;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 47px;
  right: 1px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 18px;
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;

  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.color-select {
  grid-area: color-select;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.about {
  grid-area: about;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
}

.social {
  grid-area: social;
  background-color: magenta;
  margin: 10px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: teal;
  margin: 10px;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#product-svg {
  position: absolute; /*change from relative*/
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
}

path {
  fill: #cccccc;
}

#background-image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.color {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  order: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 100.2px;
}

.red1:before,
.red1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff2600;
}

.red1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff2600;
}

.red2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #660000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 110px;
}

.red2:before,
.red2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #660000;
}

.red2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #660000;
}

.red3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #990000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: 90px;
}

.red3:before,
.red3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #990000;
}

.red3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #990000;
}

.red4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49.5px;
  left: 80px;
}

.red4:before,
.red4:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #cc0000;
}

.red4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #cc0000;
}

.red5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff6666;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: 90px;
}

.red5:before,
.red5:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff6666;
}

.red5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff6666;
}

.red6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff9999;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 110px;
}

.red6:before,
.red6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff9999;
}

.red6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff9999;
}

.red7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 120px;
}

.red7:before,
.red7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.red7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffcccc;
}

.red7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffcccc;
}

.orange1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 100.2px;
}

.orange1:before,
.orange1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff8000;
}

.orange1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff8000;
}

.orange2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #663300;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 110px;
}

.orange2:before,
.orange2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #663300;
}

.orange2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #663300;
}

.orange3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #994d00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: 90px;
}

.orange3:before,
.orange3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #994d00;
}

.orange3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #994d00;
}

.orange4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #cc6600;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: 80px;
}

.orange4:before,
.orange4:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #cc6600;
}

.orange4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #cc6600;
}

.orange5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffcc33;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: 90px;
}

.orange5:before,
.orange5:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffcc33;
}

.orange5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffcc33;
}

.orange6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffd966;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 110px;
}

.orange6:before,
.orange6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffd966;
}

.orange6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffd966;
}

.orange7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffe699;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 120px;
}

.orange7:before,
.orange7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.orange7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffe699;
}

.orange7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffe699;
}

.yellow1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 100.2px;
}

.yellow1:before,
.yellow1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffff00;
}

.yellow1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffff00;
}

.yellow2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #666600;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 110px;
}

.yellow2:before,
.yellow2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #666600;
}

.yellow2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #666600;
}

.yellow3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #999900;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: 90px;
}

.yellow3:before,
.yellow3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #999900;
}

.yellow3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #999900;
}

.yellow4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #cccc00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: 80px;
}

.yellow4:before,
.yellow4:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #cccc00;
}

.yellow4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #cccc00;
}

.yellow5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffff66;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: 90px;
}

.yellow5:before,
.yellow5:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffff66;
}

.yellow5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffff66;
}

.yellow6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 110px;
}

.yellow6:before,
.yellow6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffff99;
}

.yellow6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffff99;
}

.yellow7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 120px;
}

.yellow7:before,
.yellow7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.yellow7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffffcc;
}

.yellow7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffffcc;
}

.green1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 100.2px;
}

.green1:before,
.green1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #00ff00;
}

.green1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #00ff00;
}

.green2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #006600;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 110px;
}

.green2:before,
.green2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #006600;
}

.green2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #006600;
}

.green3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #009900;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: 90px;
}

.green3:before,
.green3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #009900;
}

.green3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #009900;
}

.green4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #00cc00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: 80px;
}

.green4:before,
.green4:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #00cc00;
}

.green4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #00cc00;
}

.green5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #66ff66;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 16px;
  left: 90px;
}

.green5:before,
.green5:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #66ff66;
}

.green5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #66ff66;
}

.green6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #99ff99;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 110px;
}

.green6:before,
.green6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #99ff99;
}

.green6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #99ff99;
}

.green7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #b3ffb3;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 120px;
}

.green7:before,
.green7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.green7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #b3ffb3;
}

.green7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #b3ffb3;
}

.blue1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #0040ff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 100.2px;
}

.blue1:before,
.blue1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #0040ff;
}

.blue1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #0040ff;
}

.blue2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #001a66;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 110px;
}

.blue2:before,
.blue2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #001a66;
}

.blue2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #001a66;
}

.blue3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #002699;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: 90px;
}

.blue3:before,
.blue3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #002699;
}

.blue3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #002699;
}

.blue4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #0033cc;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: 80px;
}

.blue4:before,
.blue4:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #0033cc;
}

.blue4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #0033cc;
}

.blue5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #3366ff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 16px;
  left: 90px;
}

.blue5:before,
.blue5:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #3366ff;
}

.blue5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #3366ff;
}

.blue6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #668cff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 110px;
}

.blue6:before,
.blue6:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #668cff;
}

.blue6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #668cff;
}

.blue7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #99b3ff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 120px;
}

.blue7:before,
.blue7:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.blue7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #99b3ff;
}

.blue7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #99b3ff;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <header class="header">

      <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="">

      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href=about.html class="nav-link">About</a>
        <a href=contact.html class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </nav>

    </header>

    <main class="main">
    </main>

    <section class="color-select">

      <div class="colors">

        <div class="red">
          <div class="color red1" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
          <div class="color red2" data-hex="#660000"></div>
          <div class="color red3" data-hex="#990000"></div>
          <div class="color red4" data-hex="#cc0000"></div>
          <div class="color red5" data-hex="#ff6666"></div>
          <div class="color red6" data-hex="#ff9999"></div>
          <div class="color red7" data-hex="#ffcccc"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="orange">
          <div class="color orange1" data-hex="#ff8000"></div>
          <div class="color orange2" data-hex="#663300"></div>
          <div class="color orange3" data-hex="#994d00"></div>
          <div class="color orange4" data-hex="#cc6600"></div>
          <div class="color orange5" data-hex="#ffcc33"></div>
          <div class="color orange6" data-hex="#ffd966"></div>
          <div class="color orange7" data-hex="#ffe699"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="yellow">
          <div class="color yellow1" data-hex="#ffff00"></div>
          <div class="color yellow2" data-hex="#666600"></div>
          <div class="color yellow3" data-hex="#999900"></div>
          <div class="color yellow4" data-hex="#cccc00"></div>
          <div class="color yellow5" data-hex="#ffff66"></div>
          <div class="color yellow6" data-hex="#ffff99"></div>
          <div class="color yellow7" data-hex="#ffffcc"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="green">
          <div class="color green1" data-hex="#00ff00"></div>
          <div class="color green2" data-hex="#006600"></div>
          <div class="color green3" data-hex="#009900"></div>
          <div class="color green4" data-hex="#00cc00"></div>
          <div class="color green5" data-hex="#66ff66"></div>
          <div class="color green6" data-hex="#99ff99"></div>
          <div class="color green7" data-hex="#b3ffb3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="blue">
          <div class="color blue1" data-hex="#0040ff"></div>
          <div class="color blue2" data-hex="#001a66"></div>
          <div class="color blue3" data-hex="#002699"></div>
          <div class="color blue4" data-hex="#0033cc"></div>
          <div class="color blue5" data-hex="#3366ff"></div>
          <div class="color blue6" data-hex="#668cff"></div>
          <div class="color blue7" data-hex="#99b3ff"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="about">e</section>
    <section class="social">f</section>
    <footer class="footer">g</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is not quite clear. I see 6 hexagons in a honeycomb shape, repeated 4 times in 4 different color families. What exactly is the issue with the placement of those honeycomb shapes?

Comment: Sweet christmas that's a lot of code. How much of this code is actually needed to demonstrate the main issue you are having? Do you need the header, navbar, main, footer, or any other section besides "color-select"? Do you even need the hexagons? Try to minimize the amount of code so that answerers can concentrate on just the problem you want solved. See [mre] for more help.

Comment: @TylerH I want the honeycomb shapes to be at the top of the green container (ie the red honeycombs to start at the top left) but I've tried every way and can't seem to make it work. The other problems it the last few honeycombs goes off on the green container. There is 5 honeycombs in the example, last one is on the right.

Comment: @luck8 It looks like all of your hexagon divs are absolutely/relatively positioned, so just change the directional properties (`top`, `left`, etc) to be values that place them where you want them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Almost all of this code is necessary; OP has a different element for each shape you see (and different styles for each one due to manually positioning them). The header/footer could go, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have much too much css involved for nowdays browsers.

Your first mistakes are to use space-between and then offsets of around 100px your hexagons ... last ones will be average 100px outside the container.

1. turn space-between to space-around, so first and last element do not stick to the edges.
2. decrease your offsets of 100px 120px becomes 20px and 80px becomes -20px , this way it remains closer to its origin area .

example from your code *(i removed uneccessary  parts and moved repeated style into a single group of rules)*

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.color-select {
  grid-area: color-select;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}


.colors {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.color {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  order: 0;
}


.red1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background: #ff0000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;

}
.color:before,
.color:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}


.red1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff2600;
}

.red1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff2600;
}

.red2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #660000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}



.red2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #660000;
}

.red2:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #660000;
}

.red3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #990000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: -10px;
}



.red3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #990000;
}

.red3:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #990000;
}

.red4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49.5px;
  left: -20px;
}


.red4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #cc0000;
}

.red4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #cc0000;
}

.red5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff6666;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: -10px;
}



.red5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff6666;
}

.red5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff6666;
}

.red6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff9999;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}



.red6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff9999;
}

.red6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff9999;
}

.red7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 20px;
}


.red7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffcccc;
}

.red7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffcccc;
}

.orange1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: .2px;
}



.orange1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ff8000;
}

.orange1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ff8000;
}

.orange2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #663300;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}


.orange2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #663300;
}

.orange2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #663300;
}

.orange3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #994d00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: -10px;
}

.orange3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #994d00;
}

.orange3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #994d00;
}

.orange4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #cc6600;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: -20px;
}

.orange4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #cc6600;
}

.orange4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #cc6600;
}

.orange5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffcc33;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: -10px;
}


.orange5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffcc33;
}

.orange5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffcc33;
}

.orange6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffd966;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}

.orange6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffd966;
}

.orange6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffd966;
}

.orange7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffe699;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 20px;
}

.orange7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffe699;
}

.orange7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffe699;
}

.yellow1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: .2px;
}


.yellow1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffff00;
}

.yellow1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffff00;
}

.yellow2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #666600;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}

.yellow2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #666600;
}

.yellow2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #666600;
}

.yellow3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #999900;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: -10px;
}


.yellow3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #999900;
}

.yellow3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #999900;
}

.yellow4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #cccc00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: -20px;
}


.yellow4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #cccc00;
}

.yellow4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #cccc00;
}

.yellow5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffff66;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: -10px;
}


.yellow5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffff66;
}

.yellow5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffff66;
}

.yellow6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}


.yellow6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffff99;
}

.yellow6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffff99;
}

.yellow7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 20px;
}

.yellow7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #ffffcc;
}

.yellow7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #ffffcc;
}

.green1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 0.2px;
}


.green1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #00ff00;
}

.green1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #00ff00;
}

.green2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #006600;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}


.green2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #006600;
}

.green2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #006600;
}

.green3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #009900;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: -10px;
}


.green3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #009900;
}

.green3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #009900;
}

.green4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #00cc00;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: -20px;
}


.green4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #00cc00;
}

.green4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #00cc00;
}

.green5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #66ff66;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 16px;
  left: -10px;
}


.green5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #66ff66;
}

.green5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #66ff66;
}

.green6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #99ff99;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}


.green6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #99ff99;
}

.green6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #99ff99;
}

.green7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #b3ffb3;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 20px;
}


.green7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #b3ffb3;
}

.green7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #b3ffb3;
}

.blue1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #0040ff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 101px;
  left: 0.2px;
}


.blue1:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #0040ff;
}

.blue1:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #0040ff;
}

.blue2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #001a66;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}


.blue2:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #001a66;
}

.blue2:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #001a66;
}

.blue3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #002699;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 82.8px;
  left: -10px;
}


.blue3:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #002699;
}

.blue3:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #002699;
}

.blue4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #0033cc;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 49px;
  left: -20px;
}


.blue4:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #0033cc;
}

.blue4:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #0033cc;
}

.blue5 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #3366ff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  top: 16px;
  left: -10px;
}

.blue5:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #3366ff;
}

.blue5:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #3366ff;
}

.blue6 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #668cff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}


.blue6:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #668cff;
}

.blue6:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #668cff;
}

.blue7 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 11.55px;
  background-color: #99b3ff;
  margin: 5.77px 0;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 20px;
}


.blue7:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 5.77px solid #99b3ff;
}

.blue7:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5.77px solid #99b3ff;
}
```

```html
<section class="color-select">

      <div class="colors">

        <div class="red">
          <div class="color red1" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
          <div class="color red2" data-hex="#660000"></div>
          <div class="color red3" data-hex="#990000"></div>
          <div class="color red4" data-hex="#cc0000"></div>
          <div class="color red5" data-hex="#ff6666"></div>
          <div class="color red6" data-hex="#ff9999"></div>
          <div class="color red7" data-hex="#ffcccc"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="orange">
          <div class="color orange1" data-hex="#ff8000"></div>
          <div class="color orange2" data-hex="#663300"></div>
          <div class="color orange3" data-hex="#994d00"></div>
          <div class="color orange4" data-hex="#cc6600"></div>
          <div class="color orange5" data-hex="#ffcc33"></div>
          <div class="color orange6" data-hex="#ffd966"></div>
          <div class="color orange7" data-hex="#ffe699"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="yellow">
          <div class="color yellow1" data-hex="#ffff00"></div>
          <div class="color yellow2" data-hex="#666600"></div>
          <div class="color yellow3" data-hex="#999900"></div>
          <div class="color yellow4" data-hex="#cccc00"></div>
          <div class="color yellow5" data-hex="#ffff66"></div>
          <div class="color yellow6" data-hex="#ffff99"></div>
          <div class="color yellow7" data-hex="#ffffcc"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="green">
          <div class="color green1" data-hex="#00ff00"></div>
          <div class="color green2" data-hex="#006600"></div>
          <div class="color green3" data-hex="#009900"></div>
          <div class="color green4" data-hex="#00cc00"></div>
          <div class="color green5" data-hex="#66ff66"></div>
          <div class="color green6" data-hex="#99ff99"></div>
          <div class="color green7" data-hex="#b3ffb3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="blue">
          <div class="color blue1" data-hex="#0040ff"></div>
          <div class="color blue2" data-hex="#001a66"></div>
          <div class="color blue3" data-hex="#002699"></div>
          <div class="color blue4" data-hex="#0033cc"></div>
          <div class="color blue5" data-hex="#3366ff"></div>
          <div class="color blue6" data-hex="#668cff"></div>
          <div class="color blue7" data-hex="#99b3ff"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Nowdays , browsers understand clip-path and CSS var() to shorten your codes , wrapping flex will need to push a bit the first element to draw your lines : 2 - 3 - 2 , justify-content and a negative margin will finish layout the hex .

possible revisited idea :

```css
[data-test] {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;/* You can let it wrap so it doesnt shrink or set offscreen children */
  justify-content:space-between;
  /* justify-content:space-around;keep off from edges */
  align-items:start;  
  /* align-items:center; whatever else you need here */
  background:linear-gradient(to top,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%) green;/* remove the gradient, it only shows the center while you need to set your alignments */
  min-height:120px;/* whatever you need here */
}

[data-test] span.color {/* the hex mother boxes */
  flex-shrink:0 ;/* needed if parent is not a wrapping flexbox */
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center; /* set in center */ 
  width:60px;/* max = 3 x 20px */
  padding-bottom:9px;/* 3 lines : 3 x 6 / 2 = 9  */
}

[data-test] span.color  span{ 
  height:23px;
  width:20px;
  background:var(--color);/* colors injected here from the var set in the style attribute */
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);/* cut your shape off */
  margin-bottom:-6px; /* overlapp the lines */
}

[data-test] span.color  span:first-child{
  margin-left:1px;/* 3x20px + px of margin on the first allows only to elements, centered from justify-content set on flex parent */
}



.color-select {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Colors stored inside a var() from a style attribute that can be used from the css file.</p>
<div data-test>
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>
  <!-- and so on with next colors -->
  
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>
</div>

<p>You can add more of course , no worries if it can wrap</p>
<div data-test>
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>
  <!-- and so on with next colors -->
  
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>  
  
  <span class="color red">
    <span style="--color: #ff0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #660000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #990000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc0000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff6666 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ff9999 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcccc "></span>
  </span>  
  <span class="color orange">
    <span style="--color: #ff8000 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #663300 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #994d00 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #cc6600 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffcc33 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffd966 "></span>
    <span style="--color: #ffe699 "></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation!!!